# Calling a method of different class using selector when button is clicked

Tags: iphone, methods, selector

I have written a method and hooked that up with a button so that it gets called when the button is clicked. Now what I want to do is to call that same method when a button on some other view is clicked.

How can I do that? Do I need to use selector or notification or simple method calling?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the selector pass the Target as object of your Class where that method is.

```
[anotherButton addTarget:objectOfAnotherClass action:@selector(yourMethodInAnotherClass) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Or

Just create a object for the class where your button method is and call that method in ordinary way

```
In First Class say firstView
-(IBAction) yourButtonMethod : (id)sender
{
   //Some Code
}

In another class
-(IBAction) yourAnotherButtonMethod : (id)sender
{
 firstView *firstViewObject = [firstView alloc] init];
 [firstViewObject yourButtonMethod:sender];
}
```

Differentiate sender by setting tagValues for buttons

Comment: Thank u so much for your so prompt response
i've tried both method, but none is gonna work... i've written the selector inside viewDidLoad() method... i.e., the following code [anotherButton addTarget:objectOfAnotherClass action:@selector(yourMethodInAnotherClass) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
Is viewDidLoad() the right place for adding selector.

And my second question is: what is the difference b/w the two methods that you mentioned above. Which should i prefere?? and in which circumstances???

Again Thank u so much
Best regards

Comment: None is working means.. Do you get any error or the method doesnt get called.

Comment: First one is the most preferred way. Second one is just normal programming way of calling methods of another class.

Comment: @iPrabu Its not working I tried with first code, its not calling another class method. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use like the blow code that u replace self by the objectOfTargetClass
and in the selector with the method need to hit in that class

```m
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```